# I NEED HELP ABOUT THİS QUESTİONS / JAVA ARRAYS

Tags: java, arrays

49 5 8 14 3 7 6 21

It gives the rank of the smallest number whose remainder is 0 after dividing by 7 in the above given index.
create the algorithm.

I WAS TRY BUT I FAİLED.. I'M YET NEW TO JAVA ..

Comment: It looks to me like you'll need to iterate through that list, and consider whether each number _might_ be the one you're looking for.  You probably have to check two different conditions in order to do that.

Comment: There is no need to SHOUT at us.

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: You say you tried. Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some hints:

To test if an integer named `x` is divisible by 7:

```
if (x % 7 == 0) {
    // x is divisible by 7
}
```

To enumerate all the items in an array name `arr`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     
}
```

Comment: Bro need me pls , how can ı write this code's. I didnt know yet,just write and send to me. is this a possible? I will look and learn after your send to me

Comment: @ersenremzi That isn't really how SO works. At the very least you should make an attempt at solving the problem and post the code with specific questions.

Comment: @ersenremzi - Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: ye,thats right but ı m really need help if ı have other changes i would never write here like this , but thanks for your advice..

Comment: So ... if you know that you need to show us your attempt ... show us your attempt.  Seriously.

Comment: I'm so confused about what to do from here https://www.hizliresim.com/nxxyxzu

Comment: I couldn't make the whole code to tell the order of the smallest value.

Comment: You can just use `for (int n : arr) ...` There is no reason to use a classic `for` loop with an index unless you really need the index for something, and here you do not.

Comment: @ersenremzi - I'm not going to do your homework for you. I've given you a great set of hints. Now google for "Java tutorial" and learn the basics or get a good book on Java.

Comment: @selbie dear master , this is not my homework and ı m not a student. Im just new in java world just I'm trying to learn. This is my practice , ım find on the google , 
I was just wondering how it's done, I'm training from udemy and this is part of my current education, no other reason but thanks you for your advice :)